# Uniswap method getAmountsOut() returns wrong value when using Hardhat mainnet fork

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat, uniswap

In my hardhat test, I'm using Uniswap's `getAmountsOut` to get the price of ETH in USD (using DAI). It currently returns $2766 as the price of ETH which is correct. Here's my test which successfully fetches the price:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ADDRESS = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
const UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ABI = [{ "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountIn", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "path", "type": "address[]" }], "name": "getAmountsOut", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "amounts", "type": "uint256[]" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }]

const DAI_ADDRESS = "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f";
const WETH_ADDRESS = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

describe("eth-price-test", function () {
    it("Test fetch Eth price", async function () {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(process.env.INFURA_WEB_SOCKET)
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.ETH_PRIVATE_KEY, provider)
        const signer = wallet.provider.getSigner(wallet.address)
        let uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
            UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ADDRESS,
            UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ABI,
            signer,
        );

        const amountEth = await uniswap.getAmountsOut(
            1,
            [WETH_ADDRESS, DAI_ADDRESS]
        )

        console.log(`1 Eth = ${amountEth[1].toString()} USD`)
    });
});
```

However when I use the signer connected to Hardhat's mainnet fork, the price returned is $3993 which is much higher. I get the signer like so:

```js
signer = ethers.provider.getSigner(process.env.ETH_PUBLIC_KEY)
let uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
  UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ADDRESS,
  UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ABI,
  signer,
);
```

And here's the relevant part of my hardhat.config.js for reference:

```js
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.5.0",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: process.env.ALCHEMY_URL
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Any idea why there's a huge price difference? Even if I peg the mainnet fork to different blocks, it always returns $3993...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix! By using `ethers.provider` when deploying the Uniswap contract instead of `signer`, `getAmountsOut()` will correctly fetch the price of Eth using the pegged block.

```js
let uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
  UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ADDRESS,
  UNISWAPV2_ROUTER02_ABI,
  ethers.provider // using provider instead of signer here
);
```